# How to sovle audio signal problem by using 1D conv neural network in keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

PS, I have change my model, but it didn't work well(64%)

I have a dataset (it is given and not a problem).

```
all_speakers = np.unique([os.path.basename(i).split('_')[1] for i in fsdd])
np.random.shuffle(all_speakers)
train_speakers = all_speakers[:2]
test_speakers = all_speakers[2:]
print("All   speakers:", all_speakers)
print("Train speakers:", train_speakers)
print("Test  speakers:", test_speakers)

train_files = [
    i for i in fsdd if os.path.basename(i).split('_')[1] in train_speakers
]
test_files = [i for i in fsdd if i not in train_files]

train = create_audio_dataset(train_files, training=True)
test = create_audio_dataset(test_files, training=False)
```

The outcome is:

> All   speakers: ['nicolas' 'theo' 'jackson']
>
> Train speakers: ['nicolas' 'theo']
>
> Test  speakers: ['jackson']

The purpose is to create a convolutional neural network, and get the accuracy over 90%.
My model is not good enough, and I don't think it is an overfitting problem.

```
model = keras.Sequential()
 model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu',input_shape=(300,40)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))  
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

n_epoch = 12
model.fit(x=train.repeat(n_epoch))
model.evaluate(test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid *maxpooling* after every Conv1D layer. In the end maxpooling destroys information (it *downsamples*) that can be critical especially in audio signals whichs analysis depends esssentially on temporal correlations. The reasons why maxpooling is used anyway are in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288261/why-is-max-pooling-necessary-in-convolutional-neural-networks. In addition you also combine *maxpooling* with *striding* what is another **downsampling**. Too much downsampling destroys information and should be avoided. The same applies for *flattening* (in image processing it destroys 2D correlations) however sometimes it is neccesary.

If you are not fixed to 1D in https://medium.com/x8-the-ai-community/audio-classification-using-cnn-coding-example-f9cbd272269e is a 2D approach with 97% accuracy.

In https://missinglink.ai/guides/keras/keras-conv1d-working-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-keras/ is the keras model for a 1D CNN for audio analysis, it uses only 1 maxpooling and no striding.